# Deciphering hospital location on death certificate from 1977

Tags: england, death-records, 1970s, wiltshire

I am trying to decipher this hospital location where my Great Grandmother died:

[image: Hospital Location]

I know it is in Salisbury but I am try to:

1. Work out the correct name.
2. Attempt to locate it online resource mentioning the hospital.

Comment: http://salisburyhealthcarehistory.uk/harnwood-hospital/ in Harnham Hill

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl You should put this as an answer.

Comment: @J.J.D. I tend not to create answers from things found froma single Google search.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl Yes but I had searched and didn’t find it. So maybe you used a certain technique? You could flesh that out in your answer. But it is up to you.

Comment: Nothing special -- just Harnwood Hospital Salisbury (as Harnwood was pretty legible and you had said Salisbury)